# Detect equality of SQL data sets from different databases

Tags: php, sql, hash

I have two independent databases (one is MySQL and the other is SQLite), and which to verify that a small amount of particular data is the same in each (however, I do not need to know what is different).  How is this accomplished?

Without a better solution, I will likely do something like the following, and see if the two data sets result in the same hash value.

```
$query = $dbMySQL->query('SELECT CONCAT(id,a,b,c) FROM myTable ORDER BY id ASC');
$hash_mysql=md5(json_encode($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)));

$query = $dbSQLite->query('SELECT id||a||b||c FROM myTable ORDER BY id ASC');
$hash_sqlite=md5(json_encode($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)));

if($hash_mysql==$hash_sqlite) {...}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the solution you have put in your question?

Comment: One issue I see with this is that SQLite uses `||` for concatenation; I'm not sure if the same `CONCAT` function works there.     Another potential  problem is the possibility that data types are output and concatenated differently among the different dbms's. May be better to just get the values and have php do the work

Comment: @Jamesking56  Maybe nothing, however, when I make up some solution, I typically find that someone previously came up with a better one.  I searched but couldn't find any, and want to make sure.

Comment: @NeilNeyman, Yes, I am brand new to SQLite and just found out how it uses `||`. I will need to do it this way for SQLite and use `CONCAT` for MySQL.  Why do you think the data types will be different?

Comment: Be careful when concatenating values; `CONCAT('123', '456') == CONCAT('12','3456')`  Be careful of format variances; A floating point value of `0` needs to be implicity cast to a string to be concatenated, that could yield `'0.00000'` on one database, `'0.'` on another, or `'0'` on another.  Similarly with Dates, Times, etc.  You're better off returning all the fields from the DB to your PHP *(rather than concatenating them)*; so that both the values and the data-types are known when creating the JSON.

Comment: @user1032531I don't think they will necessarily be different just was thinking the possibility of weirdness with date/time for example

Comment: @MatBailie  Yea, the format variances have me a bit worried.  Casting seems like a must.

Comment: @user1032531 - My suggestion is not to do the casting in the DB at all.  Don't `SELECT CONCAT(a,b,c)`, just do `SELECT a, b, c` and then deal with textual representation when building the JSON.  This decouples your extract format from the database type.